# Create a series of connectivity matrices in R

Tags: r, list, loops, matrix

Suppose I have a dataset in R indicating the membership of countries in International Organizations (the original dataset can be found here: IGO_stateunit_v2.3.zip).

Here is an example for the basic structure of the data:

```
cntr <- c('A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C')
year <- c(1990,1990,1990,1991,1991,1991,1992,1992,1992)
UNO <- c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
APEC <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,1, 1, 1 )
ASEAN <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
data <- data.frame(cntr, year, UNO, APEC, ASEAN)
```

So the data looks like this, where 1=membership in an organization, which can change over the years:

```
  cntr    year UNO APEC ASEAN
1    A    1990   0    0     0
2    B    1990   1    0     0
3    C    1990   1    0     0
4    A    1991   1    0     0
5    B    1991   1    0     1
6    C    1991   1    0     1
7    A    1992   1    1     0
8    B    1992   1    1     1
9    C    1992   1    1     1
```

What I would like to create with this data in R is a matrix for each year that counts the number of memberships two countries share together. The result should look like this:

m.1990

```
  A B C
A 0 0 0
B 0 0 1
C 0 1 0
```

m.1991

```
  A B C
A 0 1 1
B 1 0 2
C 1 2 0
```

m.1992

```
  A B C
A 0 2 2
B 2 0 3
C 2 3 0
```

Below you have the code for each year:

```
data.1990 <- subset(data, year==1990, select=-c(year))
rownames(data.1990) <- data.1990$cntr
m.1990<- tcrossprod(as.matrix(data.1990[,-1]))
diag(m.1990) <- 0

data.1991 <- subset(data, year==1991, select=-c(year))
rownames(data.1991) <- data.1991$cntr
m.1991<- tcrossprod(as.matrix(data.1991[,-1]))
diag(m.1991) <- 0

data.1992 <- subset(data, year==1992, select=-c(year))
rownames(data.1992) <- data.1992$cntr
m.1992<- tcrossprod(as.matrix(data.1992[,-1]))
diag(m.1992) <- 0
```

What I fail to do is to create a loop that does these calculations and saves each result into the corresponding matrix. I have also tried to use something like `df_list <- split(data, as.factor(data$year))` as a first step, but didn't manage to code the subsequent calculations.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this, though I didn't try to optimize your method too much

```
lapply(split(data, data$year), function(x) {
                                        rownames(x) <- x$cntr
                                        x <- tcrossprod(as.matrix(x[,-(1:2)]))
                                        diag(x) <- 0
                                        x})


# $`1990`
#   A B C
# A 0 0 0
# B 0 0 1
# C 0 1 0
# 
# $`1991`
#   A B C
# A 0 1 1
# B 1 0 2
# C 1 2 0
# 
# $`1992`
#   A B C
# A 0 2 2
# B 2 0 3
# C 2 3 0
```